# How to use json Object in jquery

Tags: jquery

Please helpme how to access Json Object or how to convert json object into Json Array

```
 var Employee = {
     "EmpId": "100",
     "Name": "xyz"
 }

 var Employee2 = [{
     "EmpId": "100",
     "Name": "xyz"
 }];

 $.each(Employee, function (i, value) {
     var xs = $('#myModal #JanMic').val(value.EmpId);
     console.log(xs);
 });
```

When i change it from `Employee` to `Employee2` its Working but why Employee is not working

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: `Employee` is just an object. `Employee2` is an array of objects (hence your `$.each` works).

Comment: could u plz see this https://jsfiddle.net/fn4v1ecr/3/

Comment: @lvan Siva Could u plz mentioned me why Employee is not working

Comment: `$.each(...)` works on Arrays only. `Employee` is *not* an array; `Employee2` is.

Comment: @peter could u plz help me how can i work on Employee

Comment: Your fiddle is erroneous. Objects are not indexed, but arrays are. That's why, `Dept[0]` is `undefined`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/fn4v1ecr/4/

Comment: `Employee` is not an array, `each()` loops through an array.

Comment: @Zakaria how can work on Employee

Comment: _how can work on Employee_ ??! what does mean ?

Comment: in my question i have 2 object 1 is Employee 2nd is Employee2 why im not work on Employee

Comment: check jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/fn4v1ecr/5/) link here i am updated the code with comment.

Comment: @Anup could u plz updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but if you need to render property's value whether it's coming from an `array` or `object` you need to check for that. See this:

```js
var Employee = {
     "EmpId": "100",
     "Name": "xyz"
 }

 var Employee2 = [{
     "EmpId": "100",
     "Name": "xyz"
 }];

function display(obj){
 if (obj instanceof Array) {
   $.each(obj, function (i, value) {
       $('#myModal #JanMic').val(value.EmpId);
   });
 } else {
  $('#myModal #JanMic').val(obj.EmpId);
 }
}

//display(Employee2)
display(Employee)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myModal">
  <input type="text" id="JanMic" />
</div>
```

I wrapped your function into `display` function and this will decide whether it can iterate through array or not. Just please bear in mind that setting a value (`.val()`) in a loop does not make much sense to me.

Comment: @siva ur really Geanious dude